# Proxyquire not overriding exported function

Tags: node.js, testing, mocking, sinon, proxyquire

I have a class `modules/handler.js`, which looks like this:

```js
const {getCompany} = require('./helper');

module.exports = class Handler {
    constructor () {...}
    async init(){
        await getCompany(){
        ...
    }
}
```

it imports the function `getCompany` from the file `modules/helper.js`:

```js
exports.getCompany = async () => {
 // async calls
}
```

Now in an integration test, I want to stub the `getCompany` method, and it should just return a mockCompany.
However, proxyquire is not stubbing the method `getCompany`, instead the real ones gets called.
The test:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire");
const Handler = require('../modules/handler');

describe('...', () => {

    const getCompanyStub = sinon.stub();
    getCompanyStub.resolves({...});

    const test = proxyquire('../modules/handler.js'), {
      getCompany: getCompanyStub
    });

    it('...', async () => {
        const handler = new Handler();
        await handler.init(); // <- calls real method 
        ... 
    });
});
```

I've also tried it out without the `sinon.stub` where proxyquire returns a function directly returning an object, however, this also did not work.

I would be very thankful for every pointer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Handler` class you are using is required by the `require` function rather than `proxyquire`.

`handler.js`:

```js
const { getCompany } = require('./helper');

module.exports = class Handler {
  async init() {
    await getCompany();
  }
};
```

`helper.js`:

```js
exports.getCompany = async () => {
  // async calls
};
```

`handler.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('69759888', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const getCompanyStub = sinon.stub().resolves({});
    const Handler = proxyquire('./handler', {
      './helper': {
        getCompany: getCompanyStub,
      },
    });
    const handler = new Handler();
    await handler.init();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  69759888
    ✓ should pass (2478ms)


  1 passing (2s)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 handler.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 helper.js  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Thanks to you I was able to pinpoint the problem. Though using  

const Handler = proxyquire('../modules/handler', {
      getCompany: getCompanyStub,
    }); 
did not work for me, but 

const Handler = proxyquire('../modules/handler', { './helpers' : { getCompany: getCompanyStub},});
worked. This seems odd to me, but I'll take it.

Comment: @seveneights Sorry, I have a typo. Updated answer. You are correct